# Sealing indoor rough cedar wall

Tags: wood, sealing, polyurethane

We have a rough cut cedar wall in a cabin that is pretty hairy and tends to flake off everywhere. I've tried sanding it but haven't had much luck, seems like it will just make it look bad. Is there any sealant I can use on indoor rough cedar like this to keep it from flaking/shedding?

Comment: Sure. Almost any varnish, urethane, sanding sealer, etc. Just pick one with the qualities you like. I'd probably avoid actual siding products due to odor and oily residue. Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: Okay - I guess I was just worried that the usual products wouldn't work well for something that's so hairy & rough.

Comment: It'll still be rough after sealing, but stuff won't be falling off. :)

Comment: You will need a "lot" of seal. I painted rough sawn cedar plywood on an exterior and it needed almost twice as much paint as normal plywood.

Comment: @isherwood make an answer out of that so it can get at least one up vote and stop this popping to the top every couple of months...

Comment: Nah. I voted to close as "needs focus". Obviously sealers exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t like the hairiness of the wood, use a screen wrapped in cloth to knock off the big pieces…go with the grain ONLY.

Cedar has an oil in it that causes it to streak and go blotchy. No other species that I know of does this.

Therefore, you must use a pre-stain before staining the wood. Do not skip this step…you’ll be sorry.